# how to prevent direct access to the php files embeded in the joomla articles?

Tags: php, iframe, referrer

I have joomla website. I put in the articles some php files into iframes. How to prevent direct view of those files? php/htaccess referrer is weak protection since anyone can set any referrer with web browser to cheat this.

Articles contains only iframes, nothing more. I put those files in iframes, because sometimes i change massively the content of those php files, which is not possible with joomla articles..

Comment: not possible. you can NOT reliably detect/prevent any kind of "direct access".

Answer (score 2):

you cannot, else the iframe will be restricted as well.

You can change massively the content of the joomla articles, use the DB.

Have iframes only is for sure NO SEO friendly.

Comment: i don't really pay attention to seo as i have the specific group of users. What do you mean saying DB? You mean database? How can i achieve this? Sorry for newbie questions, i'm using joomla because it's easy, i'm not a programmer or any kind of

Comment: DB = database. How do you make the massive update on the other files?

Comment: Thank you now i know what do you mean! :)

Comment: I just use Notepad++ to do it. Now i will make a backup of db and download it to pc then edit .sql file with notepad++ and swap specific lines with the new ones

Answer (score 0):

You can use JavaScript to prevent document from displaying as non-frame. window.top points to the, well, top window, and window points to frame window. If window.top==window, then the document is being viewed as stand-alone. At the top of your frame document put something like

```
<script>
if(window===window.top)
document.write("direct access not allowed");
</script>
```

Comment: thanks for answer, but what if in the php file are more java scripts? Should it work correctly? I put this code into the file, and when i check the file via browser it shows "direct access not allowed" and the content of the file under it :O

Comment: I thought this is what you require...not to allow direct viewing, only allow embedding in IFRAME? You can of course have more JS on the page after this, and it should be executed when you view the document in a frame or in an IFRAME.